# How do I scrape a table from a website with Python that doesn't have an ID tag or class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enOM3.jpg)[Code with table that I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZVeV.png)

It lists the "Location" but I want to find the "33 Montrose Ave." for a set of tables like this one.  I was using BeautifulSoup and Requests to pull the .url and parse it to HTML. If i could find the "location" text and use something like nextSibling etc. that would be great.  Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


website = 
requests.get("http://wakefield.patriotproperties.com/Summary.asp?
AccountNumber=6867")

content = website.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', {'class': ''})

data = soup.select("table")[0]
tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
            for row_data in data.select("tr")]
```

Comment: You'll want to share any code examples of attempts you've made so far to help people guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

your interested text is at the second table, tr, td, second b tag text.
You can easily change below code to what you want.

```
html_table = page_soup.findAll("table")[1]  # second table.
html_trs = html_table.findAll("tr")
for tr in html_trs:
    html_tds = tr.findAll("td")
    for td in html_tds:
        html_bs = td.findAll("b")
        loctext = html_bs[1].text    # second b
        loctext = loctext.lstrip()
        print("loctext=", loctext)
```

Comment: thank you very much Junhee! what you described makes sense.  i am now getting :   html_table = soup.findAll("table")[1]  # second table.
IndexError: list index out of range
there is only a few tables so I dont know why the index is incorrect. I tried 0, 1, 2 etc.

Comment: i cannot access your requests url. I just watched your html image and made sample html like that. and the sample code worked.  can you print content.

Comment: I think I know what is going on with it.  There are 3 frames set up. "top" "bottom" and "middle".  When inspecting the page in Chrome under sources, the table I want is in "Summary-bottom.asp". When I pull the content, I only am viewing the "summary.asp" This source shows the 3 Frames inside of it, each frame with a different .asp source.  I added a photo above